# Disable mysql_tzinfo_to_sql during MariaDB/MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, datetime, timezone, docker

MariaDB run in docker container hangs during initial startup while [mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](http://mysql_tzinfo_to_sql) [running](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/9ddcc2b4b0422a83dafc52e5574474dafc2fa9ca/docker-entrypoint.sh#L198) because of the [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/262).

I've disabled `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` by setting `MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO` env. var to 1.

Afterwards i manually ran:

`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | sed 's/Local time zone must be set--see zic manual page/FCTY/' | mysql -uuser -ppass --database=mysql`

It takes ~12 minutes and script causes errors in MariaDB error log if MariaDB cluster is set.

I'm wondering what's the purpose of running `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` during MariaDB installation and consequences of disabling it.

Found [this](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/populate-time-zone-data-for-mysql.html) link:

> MySQL provides developers with a rich set of Date and Time functions.
>   One of the functions is CONVERT_TZ which converts a datetime value
>   from one time zone to another. This function can use named time zones
>   such as 'MET' or 'Europe/Moscow' from the time zone information tables
>   in system database called mysql.
>
> Named time zones can be used only if the time zone information tables
>   in the mysql system database have been created and populated. The
>   MySQL installation procedure creates the time zone tables in the mysql
>   database, but does not load them with data. You need to load data
>   manually for these time zone tables.

It does answer the question.

However, i still don't fully understand practical implications of disabling populating mysql timezone system tables.

Why does timezone system tables population may take so long during initial MariaDB startup ?

Answer (score 1):

Manual is pretty clear: loaded TZs enables a TZ-related functions. Say, with TZs loaded you can transform result's datetimes due to the client's TZ automatically, or calculate FROM_UNIXTIME() with respect to the leap seconds or daysaving times etc.

Comment: and without loaded TZs, application has to do what you mentioned in its code?

Comment: @rok Yep, otherwise you have to do all the calculations on the app's side.